# Phpmyadmin sql deleting all tables in help table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables with cascade. When I do this query it deletes the correct row in main table but deletes many rows in the help table. The help table connects to ansatt table.

```
DELETE FROM `hvertirsdag` WHERE tid='15:06' AND dato='11.03.2014'
```

hvertirsdag (main table):

[image]

Ansatt_htirs (help table)

[image]

Comment: Please post the query you're executing.

Comment: As you can see the help table should have as many as rows and the main table, but I dont know why this query deleted many of the rows in the help table: DELETE FROM `hvertirsdag` WHERE tid='15:06' AND dato='11.03.2014'

Comment: Depending on what way you set up the table with cascade, when you delete a row in cascade that has a PK or FK corresponding to it, you will delete those rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

write it as

```
DELETE FROM `hvertirsdag` WHERE `tid` ='15:06' AND `hvertirsdag`.`dato`='11.03.2014'
```